# Bad address in my file I/O operation function

Tags: c, linux

I am learning Linux file I/O operation functions and trying to write a program that could creat a new file, read or write it as well as change the permissions and attributes of a file. When I try to use function "open(pathname, O_RDWR);" to get a file descriptor and use "read()" function to read current file, there is always "bad address" error. However, when I use "open(pathname, O_RDWR|O_CREATE,S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR|S_IRGRP|S_IWGRP|S_IROTH|S_IWOTH)" before write, the file will be writen currectly.
Here are the source code when I using that two function.

```
//the welcome function is a function that serve as a function nemu bar
 void Create()
{
char filepath[8];
int fd;
printf("请输入要创建的文件所在的目录及其名称：\n");
scanf("%s",&filepath);
fd = open(filepath, O_RDWR|O_CREAT, S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR|S_IRGRP|S_IWGRP|S_IROTH|S_IWOTH );//总是以默认的方式创建文件
if(fd == -1)
{
    printf("创建失败，请重新输入文件名及其所在目录创建\n");
    sleep(5);
    Create();
}
else
{
    char is;
    printf("创建成功！是否对新创建的文件进行写操作？");
    scanf("%s",&is);
    if(is == 'y'||is == 'Y')
        Write(fd,filepath);
    else if(is == 'n'||is == 'N')
    {
        close(fd);
        welcome();
    }
    else
    {
        printf("您的输入有误，回到欢迎界面中…\n");
        close(fd);
        sleep(5);
        welcome();
    }
  }
}
void Write(int fd, char *path)
{
volatile int len;
if(fd == -1)
{
    len = 0;
    char filepath[8];
    printf("请输入要写的文件的完整路径及其名称：");
    scanf("%s",&filepath);
    fd = open(filepath, O_RDWR);
    if(fd == -1)
    {
        perror("open during write");
        Write(-1, "");
    }
    char w1[BUFFERSIZE], *w;
    printf("请输入要写入文件的内容，以回车结束：\n");
    scanf("%s",&w1);
    w = w1;
    //用于写入的模块
    int n = 1;
    while(n > 0)
    {
        if(n = write(fd, w+len, (strlen(w)-len))<0)
        {
            perror("write");
            return; 
        }
        len += n;
    }
    char is;
    printf("是否查看写入的内容？");
    scanf("%s",&is);

    if(is == 'Y'||is == 'y')
    {
        close(fd);
        Read(filepath,strlen(w));
    }
    else
    {
        close(fd);
        welcome();
    }
}
else
{
    printf("请输入要写入文件的数据：\n");
    char w1[BUFFERSIZE];
    char *w;
    scanf("%s",&w1);
    w = w1;
    len = 0;
    int n = 1;
    while(n > 0)
    {
        n = write(fd, w+len, (strlen(w)-len));
        len += n;
    }
    char is;
    printf("是否查看写入的内容？");
    scanf("%s",&is);
    if(is == 'Y'||is == 'y')
    {
        close(fd);
        Read(path,strlen(w));
    }
    else
    {
        close(fd);
        welcome();
    }
  }
};
```

Could you please help me solve this question? I would be highly appreciated if you could help me!

Comment: `char filepath[8]; scanf("%s",&filepath);` is not good for the extra `&`, and `char is; scanf("%s",&is);` is bad for lack of space (high risk of out-of-range access).

Comment: Calling `Create` from inside that function when it fails is not good. Study [recursions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) a bit more. `filepath` must be large, declare it as `filepath[MAX_PATH]` at a bare minimum (include limits.h). The variable `filepath` is already a pointer to an array of chars, so no need to use `&` for it in `scanf`.

Comment: Also, welcome to SO. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking questions like this. It will help us give you better answers.